# SSIS XML Task with Untyped XML

Tags: sql, xml, ssis

I am pretty new to loading data from XML data sources into SQL Server, but I have had success with a properly formatted XML data source in the past. I have a web service that is being called through SSIS from a third party solution to get data out. This web service spits the data out like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<EpsTableEx xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <ErrorString />
  <ErrorNum>1</ErrorNum>
  <Data>
    <ArrayOfString>
      <string>ObjectId</string>
      <string>Form_Type</string>
      <string>Owner</string>
      <string>CompletedDate</string>
      <string>Delivered</string>
      <string>Name</string>
      <string>EventID</string>
    </ArrayOfString>
    <ArrayOfString>
      <string>183122</string>
      <string>Form1</string>
      <string>91b</string>
      <string>2015-03-02</string>
      <string>2015-04-22</string>
      <string>Onboarding</string>
      <string>21966</string>
    </ArrayOfString>
    <ArrayOfString>
      <string>183152</string>
      <string>Form1</string>
      <string>2879d</string>
      <string>2015-03-02</string>
      <string>2015-04-22</string>
      <string>Onboarding</string>
      <string>21967</string>
    </ArrayOfString>
  </Data>
</EpsTableEx>
```

The first ArrayOfString is the column headers, instead of the each element being a column header.

In another package with a properly formatted XML web service, I am using an XML Task Editor to get down to the data level with an XPATH Operation, which doesn't work for me here.  This results in the ArrayOfString and String being stripped out and all of the data is concatenated together.

I have tried:

1. Changing the XPATH Operation to different levels of the XML path without success.
2. Altering the XSD file to try to force it to think the text within the ArrayOfString tag would be the text to insert into the table and then parse it later, but no data came through.
3. Altering the XSD file to have String1, String2, etc. for the fields defined, hoping it will map to the generic string tags for each item.

I am using SQL Server 2014 and Data Tools to build the SSIS Package.

**EDIT:
The goal would be to have a solution within SSIS that can be ran nightly.**

**Edit2:**
The data would be loaded into a table like below:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FormXML](

[ObjectID] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[Form_Type] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[Owner] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[CompletedDate] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[Delivered] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[Name] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[EventID] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[ADD_DTTM] [datetime] NULL DEFAULT (getdate()))
```

I don't care about the ErrorString or ErrorNum nodes. I adapted the suggested XML query to insert the data into the table using an Execute SQL Task.

The XML that is getting put into the variable in SSIS is +400k characters. I read online that there was a 2GB limit to a string variable according to this article (http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/SQL+Server/97947/). I suspect this is my issue, and I wouldn't be having this problem if i could load the XML from the web service into an XML Variable instead of a string variable.

Comment: You might have to write a custom C# script component source to properly parse the XML :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this using 2 different variables. I fed the XML Output of the Web service into a string variable, let's call it `String1`. Then I created another variable, called `String2`, and created an expression to format the `String1` into a usable XML String.

My Expression below replaces all instances of "\n", "\r", and " xmlns=\"http://Eprise\"" to get the string formatted properly. Then I used the SUBSTRING expression to only get the porting of the string within the data tags. The FINDSTRING located where the data tag started and the LEN helped find how long the string should actually be.

```
replace(
    replace(
        replace(
            substring(@[User::String1], 
                      FINDSTRING( @[User::String1] , "<Data", 1) , 
                      LEN( 
                        substring(@[User::String1], 
                                  FINDSTRING( @[User::String1] , 
                                            "<Data", 
                                            1),
                                  LEN(@[User::String1])
                                  )
                        ) -13 
                    )
            ,"\n","")
        ,"\r","")
    ," xmlns=\"http://Eprise\"","")
```

I had to populate an initial value in `String1` that was at least 13 characters so that I could trim the end off of `String1` to remove the last closing tag. I also needed the initial value to contain the text "String2 to evaluate to true initially.

Once `String2` was formatted, I used and Execute SQL Task. I added a Parameter, using `String2` as an Input direction of NVARCHAR type with a name of 0 and length of 2147483647, which is 2 gb, the max for a string in SSIS.

I tweaked the SQL Query from @[Shnugo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5089204/shnugo) to:

```
declare @x as xml

set @x=?

insert into Database.dbo.Table ([ObjectID] ,[Form_Type],[Owner],[CompletedDate],[Delivered],[Name],[EventID])

SELECT block.value('string[1]', 'varchar(max)') AS ObjectId
    ,block.value('string[2]', 'varchar(max)') AS Form_Type
    ,block.value('string[3]', 'varchar(max)') AS OWNER
    ,block.value('string[4]', 'varchar(max)') AS CompletedDated
    ,block.value('string[5]', 'varchar(max)') AS Delivered
    ,block.value('string[6]', 'varchar(max)') AS NAME
    ,block.value('string[7]', 'varchar(max)') AS EventID
FROM @x.nodes('/Data/ArrayOfString[position()>1]') AS ArrayOfString(block)
```

The ? pulls in the value from the parameter which was my formatted XML String and then inserted the data into the table using the XML Query.

Comment: Great! One last thing: You should mark one given answer as accepted (the check below the vote counter), to mark this issue as resolved. If you do this at the best answer you got from somebody else (in this case there's only mine :-) ) this person is happy with 15 reputation points, You can mark your own answer too (no reputation points in this case...). Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that this XML is carrying a "table" with data rows I'd suggest not to take the column names from the first block. They can be "hard coded" probably:

Just paste this into an empty SQL query window and execute. Adapt it to your needs...

```
declare @x XML='<EpsTableEx xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <ErrorString />
  <ErrorNum>1</ErrorNum>
  <Data>
    <ArrayOfString>
      <string>ObjectId</string>
      <string>Form_Type</string>
      <string>Owner</string>
      <string>CompletedDate</string>
      <string>Delivered</string>
      <string>Name</string>
      <string>EventID</string>
    </ArrayOfString>
    <ArrayOfString>
      <string>183122</string>
      <string>Form1</string>
      <string>91b</string>
      <string>2015-03-02</string>
      <string>2015-04-22</string>
      <string>Onboarding</string>
      <string>21966</string>
    </ArrayOfString>
    <ArrayOfString>
      <string>183152</string>
      <string>Form1</string>
      <string>2879d</string>
      <string>2015-03-02</string>
      <string>2015-04-22</string>
      <string>Onboarding</string>
      <string>21967</string>
    </ArrayOfString>
  </Data>
</EpsTableEx>';

SELECT ArrayOfString.block.value('string[1]','int') AS ObjectId
      ,ArrayOfString.block.value('string[2]','varchar(max)') AS Form_Type
      ,ArrayOfString.block.value('string[3]','varchar(max)') AS [Owner]
      ,ArrayOfString.block.value('string[4]','date') AS CompletedDated
      ,ArrayOfString.block.value('string[5]','date') AS Delivered
      ,ArrayOfString.block.value('string[6]','varchar(max)') AS [Name]
      ,ArrayOfString.block.value('string[7]','int') AS EventID
FROM @x.nodes('/EpsTableEx/Data/ArrayOfString[position()>1]') AS ArrayOfString(block)
```

Comment: This works within SSMS, but not through SSDT. It will complete, but not insert any rows. And you stripped out the first line of the XML.

Comment: @WyattShipman, I do not understand what you are missing. This SQL doesn't insert anything because there is not INSERT statement :-) You did not give enough information what you are going to do with this: Where to insert? How is the structure of the target table? What are you going to do with ErrorString and ErrorNum? And: I did not strip out the first line, SQL Server won't allow you to set the encoding with a <?xml ...?> directive. Please come back with further questions/information...

Comment: I updated my post with an edit. I expect another solution would be to try and write the XML returned from the service to an XML file, but then I would need a way to remove that encoding directive...

Comment: @WyattShipman, There must be one point, where the web service hands over the XML. At this stage it should be "complete". Where's the first stage you handle this data? Is the XML's structure under your control? What type has the SQL variable you want to write it in? How do you write it in?

Comment: When the web service "hands over the data" it looks like my OP. I don't have any control on how the web service "hands over the data" because it comes from a 3rd party solution. Using SSIS, the first time I touch it is where to assign the output, I can write it to a file or store it in a string variable. There isn't an option to store it into an XML variable in SSIS that I know of, so I have tried both the file and the string variable.  In the end, I'd like to load it into a SQL Server Table.

Comment: @WyattShipman, I'm not familiar with SSIS, but I found this: http://milambda.blogspot.co.at/2014/02/sql-server-integration-services-data.html If I understand it correctly you could take it "as object" and hand it to SQL Server as VARBINARY(MAX). The content of VARBINARY(MAX) is converted to XML quite easily...

Comment: Thanks for the direction, that link was helpful in solving my issue, as well as your query suggestion. I'll post my answer as to how this was solved.